# Why won't we have a "Want a job?" box in the right sidebar here as in StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

Drupal job offerings in the a box in the right sidebar can be very nice, I think... Just as the ones in StackOverflow about programming and Front-end dev.

Answer (score 2):

You need 6 votes to get that, post it as answer in the following link

[Community Promotion Ads - 2016](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/community-promotion-ads-2016)

Comment: 6 votes per one answer I guess (I think I have that)...

Comment: Where I can see this option? I can found it